# preg_match id number after text

Tags: php

I'm trying to retrieve id from $_POST, but it never enters the `preg_match` if.

what i've tried:

```
echo "<b>Image: </b><input type='text' name='image_" . $row['id'] . "' value='";


...
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
        if (preg_match('^image_(\d*)$', $key, $matches))
            {
            $id = $matches[1];
            if (isset($_POST['title_' . $id]))
                {
                mysql_query("UPDATE table SET title='" . $_POST['title_' . $id] . "' where id='$id'");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
'^image_(\d*)$'
```

should be (for example):

```
'/^image_(\d*)$/'
```